# Are LL(1) grammars a subset of LR(0) grammars?

Tags: automata, parsers, lr-k

As far as I've understood it seems that LL1 are a subset of LR0, but studying the following grammar I end up in a contraddiction.

Grammar :

S -> (S) | [S] | {S} | ε

This is an LL1 while it seems to me that it isn't LR0 because of a conflict shift-reduce in the initial state I0 of the LR0 automa caused by this:

S -> . (reduce)

S -> .(S) (shift)

S -> .[S] (shift)

S -> .{S} (shift)

Going forward it seems that is an SLR(1) because we haven't any kinds of conflicts.

Comment: Every LL(1) grammar is also LR(1), but not all LR(1) grammars are LL(1). https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36652221/relationship-between-lr0-ll0-lalr1-etc